# PHP: showing every if every user's online or not

Tags: php

How can I filter out online users, if I have a column "`lastaccess`" that have a unix time() stamp. Then I usually have this function:

```
function showStatus($userid) {
    $timeoutIdle = 80;
    $timeoutOffline = 150;
    $row = mysql_query("select last_access from users where id='$userid'");
    $read = mysql_fetch_array($row);
    $last_access = $read["last_access"];
    $thetime = time();
    if ($thetime - $last_access > $timeoutOffline) {
        echo "";
    }
    else if ($thetime - $last_access > $timeoutIdle) {
        echo "<span class='statusIdle'>Idle</span>";
    } else {
        echo "<span class='statusOnline'>Online</span>";
    }
}
```

How do I make a query, where it displays if you're online?

Comment: what do you mean? You can already see if the user is online. Or would you like to change the query so that the result will include info if the user is online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT
          CASE
            WHEN last_access < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-150 THEN 'offline'
            WHEN last_access < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-80 THEN 'idle'
            ELSE 'online'
          END AS online_status
        FROM users
        WHERE id = $userid";
```

Comment: Yes, that works. That'll give you all the fields in the user table, followed by the "online_status" field.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has some functions related to [Date/Times](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Check out `NOW()` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. You could add this to your query where clause to `SELECT` only online users.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOW() - last_access < 80;
```

Or use an `CASE` statement to determine the status string for a given user

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN (NOW() - last_access > 150) THEN 'offline'
WHEN (NOW() - last_access > 80) THEN 'idle'
ELSE 'online' END AS status
FROM users WHERE id = $user_id;
```

Comment: Nice edit.. `END CASE AS` does not work though; use `END AS`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say an easier way to do it is,
when a user logs in update the status field for that user:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET status='online' WHERE id='$userid'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Then on the page where you want to see if they are online add this:

```
$status = mysql_query("SELECT online FROM table
 WHERE id='$searched_user'") or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $status );

if($row['status'] == "online"){
echo "Online";
}
else{
echo "Offline";
}
```

Then when they click log out or when the cookie/session has expired:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET status='offline' WHERE id='$userid'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```